# Aligning three element in CSS

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm looking to get the dots aligned, fixed, and should not move. This is what I need it to look like:

[image]

This is what I have so far below. As you can see if there are double digits, the dot moves.

[image]

This is what I'm rendering on the DOM. As you can see I have separated all three items into their own span.

```
<div className="Legend-Component col-3" align="center">
   {legendData.map((item, index) => (
       <ul key={index}>
           <li>
             <span className="Legend-Name" onClick={() => this.handleClick(item.assetManagerId)}> 
                {item.name}
             </span>
             <span className={`${item.className[index]}`}></span>
             <span className="Legend-Total">{item.total}</span>
           </li>
        </ul>
    ))}
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.Legend-Component ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      font-size: 12px;
      text-align: right;
      margin: auto;
  }
  .Legend-Name{
    color: #006192;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .Legend-Total {
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  .navy {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    background-color: #001f3f;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid grey;
  }
  .blue {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 13px;
    width: 13px;
    background-color: #0074D9;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    margin: 0 2px;
  }
  .aqua {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 13px;
    width: 13px;
    background-color: #7FDBFF;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    margin: 0 2px;
  }
  .teal {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 13px;
    width: 13px;
    background-color: #39CCCC;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    margin: 0 2px;
  }
```

Comment: This almost looks like it could be some sort of data that could be organised into a `<table>`…

Comment: Please post your rendered HTML.

Comment: Hey @BenM, my first code block shows what's being rendered to the DOM.

Comment: @chriskirknielsen. That's probably a good idea! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make each list item a `flex` item. Allow the left and right elements to fill the available space with `flex: 1`.

This will keep the circles centred.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.circle {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 13px;
    width: 13px;   
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    margin: 0 2px;
}

.blue {
  background-color: #0074D9;
}

/* The important bits... */

.legend-item {
  display: flex;
}

.legend-name {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: right;
}

.legend-total {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div className="Legend-Component col-3">
  <ul key={index}>
    <li class="legend-item">
      <span class="legend-name"> 
        Legend Name
      </span>
      <span class="circle blue"></span>
      <span class="legend-total">00</span>
    </li>
    <li class="legend-item">
      <span class="legend-name"> 
        Legend Name
      </span>
      <span class="circle blue"></span>
      <span class="legend-total">000</span>
    </li>
    <li class="legend-item">
      <span class="legend-name"> 
        Legend Name Long
      </span>
      <span class="circle blue"></span>
      <span class="legend-total">0</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

If you need to align the circles off-centre, you may have to play with the `flex-basis`:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.circle {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 13px;
    width: 13px;   
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    margin: 0 2px;
}

.blue {
  background-color: #0074D9;
}

/* The important bits... */

.legend-item {
  display: flex;
}

.legend-name {
  flex: 1;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  text-align: right;
}

.legend-total {
  flex: 1;
  flex-basis: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div className="Legend-Component col-3">
  <ul key={index}>
    <li class="legend-item">
      <span class="legend-name"> 
        Legend Name
      </span>
      <span class="circle blue"></span>
      <span class="legend-total">00</span>
    </li>
    <li class="legend-item">
      <span class="legend-name"> 
        Legend Name
      </span>
      <span class="circle blue"></span>
      <span class="legend-total">000</span>
    </li>
    <li class="legend-item">
      <span class="legend-name"> 
        Legend Name Long
      </span>
      <span class="circle blue"></span>
      <span class="legend-total">0</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```